# Android bluetooth sending continuous messages as separate objects

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to send progress values (actually hashmaps that contain progress values) from one device to another over bluetooth, so that both devices can display the same progress dialog value

So on the sender device I'm wrapping the value up in a hashmap (so I can differentiate between message types by checking the first element):

```
public static void sendProgress(Integer progress){
        HashMap<String,String> saveProgress = new HashMap<>();
        saveProgress.put("type", "saveProgress");
        saveProgress.put("progressValue", Integer.toString(progress));
        BTService.connectedThread.write(MainActivity.gson.toJson(saveProgress).getBytes());
    }
```

On the receiving side I'm reading the message stream like this:

```
        while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that because its not actually sending an object, its just sending a stream of bytes, the receiving device doesn't know when one "object" ends and the next begins.

Is there a way to rewrite my read input stream code so that it can treat each individual hash map as objects?

I know that I can add some sort of character to the end of the json string before I convert it to bytes, and then check for the character on the receiving side, but I'm sending a lot of data all throughout my app and would rather not have to refactor everything

One thing I've tried is adding a terminator whenever I write on the sender device:

```
            //Set the termination character (#)
            byte[] stopBytes = "#".getBytes();
            byte[] tempArray = new byte[bytes.length + stopBytes.length];

            //Attach a terminator to the message
            //copy bytes into start of destination (from pos 0, copy bytes.length bytes)
            System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, tempArray, 0, bytes.length);
            //copy stopBytes into end of destination (from pos bytes.length, copy stopBytes.length bytes)
            System.arraycopy(stopBytes, 0, tempArray, bytes.length, stopBytes.length);

            Log.d(TAG, new String(tempArray));

            //Write the object with terminator attached
            mmOutStream.write(tempArray);
```

In the case of sending across data like sensor data in a hashmap, I can confirm that it is sending something like this:

```
{"gravX":"0.39","accZ":"9.929751","magZ":"-27.125","accY":"0.60594","magY":"10.5","gravY":"0.7","accX":"0.44547364","magX":"23.3125","gravZ":"9.7699995","type":"accData"}#
```

Then on the receiving side I read each byte of the input stream and check for a terminator. If its found, then send the message, otherwise keep reading:

```
                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer[bytes] = (byte) mmInStream.read();
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                if ((buffer[bytes] == '#')){
                    //Check for terminator (#) before sending the message/object
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    bytes=0;
                } else{
                    bytes++;
                }
```

I get some errors with this method though, because in some cases the object I end up receiving is something like:

```
{"gravX":"0.39","accZ":"9.903406","magZ":"-26.3125","accY":"0.6394702","magY":"9.8125","gravY":"0.62","accX":"0.41912845","magX":"25.5625","gravZ":"9.78","type":"accData"}#}#ata"}
```

As you can see it isnt splitting by terminator correctly, and also adds some other junk to the end. Obviously this is a problem when I try to turn this back into a useable hashmap on the receiving side. Where do these extra characters come from?

Comment: How did you solve this... we have a similar issue, we already use an terminator char, but we don't like it, because it doesn't allow to use the char anymore in the data... and we don't have control about what will be send and what not.